# Google Cloud Endpoints passes object with null fields when calling dev server (on localhost)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, google-cloud-endpoints

I currently face a strange situation when invoking Google Cloud Endpoints from an iOS client whereby my service receives a legit object when its instance on `appspot.com` is called, but the same object's fields are all set to `null` when the instance on the dev server on `localhost` (launched from inside Eclipse) is called.

The `java.version` on `appspot.com` is `1.7.0`, on `localhost` it is `1.7.0_45` (i.e. Oracle Java 7 on OS X). From the log files the JSON passed in the HTTP request looks okay and deserialization reports normal activity in both cases.

Has anybody else also encountered this situation and solved the problem for the development server (i.e. on `localhost`)?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem right now :/

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set HTTPMethod of "Post" to the method annotation? Example:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "setMyObject", path = "myObjectMethod", httpMethod = "POST")
public MyResponse setMyObject(MyClass obj) {}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and the httpMethod is POST, but I am still facing the problem.

Comment: Are you sending an actual HTTP POST request from the client or the API explorer? Can you attach a code snippet?

Comment: This is my method signature:
@ApiMethod(path = "User/profile/update", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public UserProfileDto updateProfile(@Named("sessionToken") String sessionToken, UserProfileDto newProfile) throws UnauthorizedException { /* Do some work */}

It works fine from API Explorer, I am using the auto-generated RPC API for the iOS client. Everything goes fine, and all my request with simple String types works just fine. However the requests using the Dto doesn't work. The Dto is not null when received in the backend, but all its fields are.

Comment: I just tried downloading the Cloud Backend Starter example for Java and the corresponding sample client for iOS. I commented out the push-notification stuff, so I could run the sample in the simulator. It has the same behavior with null fields in the Dto objects, so I guess it is not my code. Maybe some configuration that needs to be done.

Comment: I have a similar situation with javascript client.  On the devserver (localhost) if my object is missing fields, they come as null to the endpoint implementation.  On prod .appspot.com the call gets rejected with "missing required field" for an @Named field

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I've found that I need to redeploy the openapi specification to the production server, for my local instance to recognise a new or updated method definition. I have no idea why this is or why that would make sense, but it may be worth trying.